# Unable to see Android logs in react-native app using adb logcat: no matches found: *:S

Tags: react-native

According to the official [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html), typing `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` in the terminal will display all the Android Logs, however when I do so I get the following error message: `no matches found: *:S`. I have put Log statements in my custom native modules like so : 
`Log.e(TAG, "Unsupported media type:" + type);`.I searched for this problem online and found no solution(No one has had the same error as me, apparently).

I would like to add that the code is working fine.

Comment: Same here, Log.e dose not seem to work in React Native

Comment: try with quotes around the filter: `adb logcat '*:S' ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`

Comment: That was it! Thanks @antoine129

Answer (score 18):

Try using:

```
adb logcat -s ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```

Source:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Answer (score 12):

I am assuming that you are using zsh for the terminal. Try using it like this

`adb logcat '*:S' ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Useful to debug native errors (when the app won't even start)

`adb logcat "*:E"`

Useful to debug JS code errors

`adb logcat "*:S" ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`

Answer (score -2):

Try using:

`adb logcat -d`

-d Dump the error log on the screen 
Instead of using the adb logcat which displays everything on the screen,things you need and things you don't need

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html

Comment: adb logcat -d help you to dump the device error log on the command screen